# Quicker Way to Compile Long Arguments

Tags: linux, command-line

I want to know if there is a quicker way to compile long lines of arguements

Example:

```
 gcc -std=c99 -Iheaders folder/file.c folder/file2.c folder/file3.c
```

I want to input this line with a shortcut (not Ctrl V)

Example if i were to type in a certain word:

```
 compilefile
```

It would function the same as the gcc code listed above on command line.

Comment: Sounds like time to learn about makefiles (or something similar for another build system).

Comment: This has nothing to do with C++. Just because a C++ is being executed, this does not make this a C++ question.

Comment: take a look at cmake...

Comment: Not sure why the down votes. For a new programmer, it's a reasonable question. As others have said, it's good to learn about `make` and makefiles. But until  a program gets to be more than a few thousand lines, it's also fine to use a simple shell script that runs the compilation command just as you've given it: probably `bash` for Linux; `cmd` or `powershell` for  Windows.  If you're using `bash`, you can also define a simple alias in the file `~/.aliases`.

Comment: @Gene: There are other and better build-tools than `make`, e.g. SCons. `make` only still exists because people don't know anything else and still recommend it. - Got it? The question is primarily opinion-based and leads to discussion.

Answer (score -1):

Absolutely! [Makefiles](http://mrbook.org/blog/tutorials/make/) are your friend.